# How can I force a tab stop in my AngularJS directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am creating a custom checkbox directive for my app, however, tab skips right over it.  How can I force the tab key to stop at my directive?

Code:  (Note: Plunker seems to be on the fritz right now...)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller='TestCtrl'>
        <input type='text' />
        <test-checkbox ng-model='isChecked'></test-checkbox>
        <input type='text' />  
    </div>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module("testApp", []);

        app.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.isChecked = true;
        }]);

        app.directive('testCheckbox', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                scope: {
                    isChecked: "=ngModel"
                },
                link: function (scope, element) {
                    var html = 
                        "<div class='slgCheckbox' ng-click='onClick(isChecked = !isChecked)'>" +
                        $(element).html() +
                        "<i class='checkboxIcon glyphicon' ng-class='{\"glyphicon-check\" : isChecked === true, \"glyphicon-unchecked\" : isChecked === false }'></i>" +
                        "</div>";

                    var compiledHtml = $compile(html)(scope);
                    $(element).replaceWith(compiledHtml);
                }
            }
        }]);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 1):

You can add a tabindex attribute to the div element and that will make it selectable.

In your template above, you can do something like this:

```
var html = 
     "<div tabindex='1' class='slgCheckbox' ng-click='onClick(isChecked = !isChecked)'>" +
      $(element).html() +
      "<i class='checkboxIcon glyphicon' ng-class='{\"glyphicon-check\" : isChecked === true, \"glyphicon-unchecked\" : isChecked === false }'></i>" +
       "</div>";
```

Note that the tabindex attribute must go on the div element.

Thought, this is a bit of a simplistic answer for 2 reasons:

1. You will not always want a tabindex of 1. It will need to be relative to other elements of the page.
2. Just because it can be given focus, pressing space will not cause the onclick handler to be invoked. You will need some custom logic for that through using the onkeypress handler.

Your best bet is to use an input element as best as you can so that you can leverage native select handling.

For more information see [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534654%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).